# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' error occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014-express

I am making telephone dairy and one error is coming

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Please tell me where I am doing wrong this is my code error comes in this line `con.Open();`

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Telephone
{
    public partial class Phone : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =ZOHAB/SQLEXPRESS;
     Initial Catalog = bscs; Integrated Security = True");

        public Phone()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Phone_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Clear();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (@"INSERT INTO 5th

                (First Name,Last Name,Mobile,Email,Catagory)

                VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "')",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the connection string to `@"Data Source=ZOHAB\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bscs;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: Handle exception (try catch) block and read the actual messsage.

Comment: Further to Hak's comment above, try looking in the InnerException for further detail.

Comment: David Arno I have tried to change the connection string as you said above  but now error is coming here in this line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"